# Why does my Android app look for /data/app/package_name-1/lib/arm/libLibrary.so instead of using the folder armeabi

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I get this in logcat when trying to load a library compiled only for armeabi (assuming that it is the fallback for all arm* abis).

```
    08-14 09:43:51.516    7486-7486/package_name E/art﹕ dlopen("/data/app/package_name-1/lib/arm/libLibrary.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: unknown reloc type 160 @ 0xa3725ab4 (82108)
```

Due to practical constraints, I cannot test this on a rooted device, so all I know is that the `/data/data/package_name` folder has a symlink `lib -> /data/app/package_name-1/lib/arm`

I know that this is not a device specific problem, since I have used native libraries earlier on the same device (with a different app, but same architecture earlier).

Can someone help me out here? Really confused on what exactly is happening.

I use gradle build (Android Studio), and the libLibrary.so is present inside the `lib/armeabi` folder within the apk on unzipping it.

Comment: i gues android-studio works with jniLib folder with all .so files into it.

Comment: @N5. - On extracting the built apk, I can find the .so file present within the `lib/armeabi` folder, can it still be a problem with the jniLib folder?

Comment: i have tried with .so files in libs folder but android studio didnt picked it up ...possibly add it into ../main/jinLib/armeabi/.so file

Answer (score 1):

The question was only partially correct. The true problem was with the relocation type (of which I had no idea initially).

Relocation errors usually occur when the loader and the object file do not understand the same format.

In this case, the .so file was built with `c++_static` instead of `gnustl_static`. Android/NDK provides most `c++11` functionality, but some of them are not fully operational/functional like `std::to_string` which led me to try `c++_static`.

Hope this helps someone else out there who still has hairs left on his/her head.